# Configuring journald.service to log its own debug_log messages

Tags: linux, logging, systemd

I have a Linux server that is rotating its logs every hour or so, and I'd like to understand why.

I noticed that journald itself contains [debug logging, like this,](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/df8fd03a7dcf2f06cd9e2ee3eed60c3a83b43ccc/src/libsystemd/sd-journal/journal-file.c#L4129) that might explain it. But I checked the system log, and the messages are not there. It seems that, like any other program, journald has its own internal debug logging disabled by default. (It seems to be controlled by [this variable](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/df8fd03a7dcf2f06cd9e2ee3eed60c3a83b43ccc/src/basic/log.c#L43) which defaults to `LOG_INFO`.)

**How can I tell journald to log these messages?**

(Note: I am *not* looking for the `MaxLevelStore=` setting in journald.conf. That is already defaulted to `Debug` on my system, but it only comes into play after a program decides to log something. The problem is that journald is deciding *not* to log anything. I'm looking for something more like the `[Manager] LogLevel=` setting in systemd-system.conf.)

Answer (score 2):

Run `systemctl edit systemd-journald` to add the environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Save and exit, then restart the service.

Note that unlike other systemd services, journald's own messages will not go to the journal – they will be logged to the kernel log buffer, i.e. `dmesg` (and will not be imported from there back into the journal, either).